# PySide QFileDialog window size

Tags: pyqt, pyside

As far as I understand widget window size could be defined by calling 'setGeometry' function.

```
import_dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
import_dialog.setWindowTitle('Import File')
import_dialog.setDirectory(FILE_DIR)
import_dialog.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
import_file, _ = import_dialog.getOpenFileNames()
print(import_file)
```

But when I'm executing this part of my gui code, I'm facing pop up window that covers entire screen. I tried to make it smaller by calling 'setGeometry' function but with no results.

How can I make it to appear smaller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getOpenFileNames` is a convenience static method of the `QFileDialog` class. It should handle creating the dialog, setting the right size as appropriate for your OS, and retrieving the result. Try calling it like this:

```
filenames, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(parent, "Select file", FILE_DIR)
```

If that does not help, you can create the dialog yourself (as you did) and call `show()`, change the size, and bind the `fileSelected` signal to a slot.