# How to adjust the QFileDialog's size in pyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

Here is part of my code about show the QFileDialog.

```
expand='Image Files(*.mp3 *.wav)'
tips=u'choose the music file'
path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, tips, QtGui.QDesktopServices.storageLocation(QtGui.QDesktopServices.MusicLocation), expand)
```

Then it can show the window to choose file.
But its size is too big for me.
I want to set up the size is 320*240.
However I don't know how to do.
Hope there is anyone can solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890938/pyside-qfiledialog-window-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only option is not to use the convenience function `getOpenFileName`.
You will need to create the Dialog by yourself and connect its signal.

Something like this:

```py
def fileSelected(self, filename):
    print(filename)

def showDialog(self):
    filedialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    filedialog.fileSelected.connect(self.fileSelected)
    filedialog.setFixedSize(320,240)
    filedialog.show()
```